# How to fill unconnected areas in polygon with the same attribute

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3

I am trying to fill in the gaps with the same attribute. [image: city of Westbank] These arrowed areas belong to a city called 'Westbank', but the thing is, these areas are unconnected, how can I make a polygon out of areas by making sure these 2 areas will be unconnected? Can I even do this in QGIS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would approach this, considering you are looking to fill the holes in the Main Polygon (I will call it the City Polygon - First Image) with a new Polygon - "Westbank" would be to use the "Difference" Tool in QGIS.

First, create a new Polygon Shapefile in QGIS, call it "Westbank".
Toggle Editing and draw rough polygons / or a single polygon around the holes in the City Polygon - make sure you do not "draw outside" of the City Polygon Boundary. See below:
[image: City Polygon - Initial]
[image: Westbank Polygons]

Next, under the "Processing Toolbox" find the "Vector Overlay" Tool and then then the "Difference" Tool.

Input is the "WestBank Polygon" and the Overlay is the "City Polygon".
Hit run and the output will be Polygons / A polygon (depending on how you digitised the initial shapes) filling the holes in the City Polygon.

You can then decide how you want to fill in the attributes / dissolve into a single feature...[[image: Example]] 
[image: Final Result]

Answer (score 3):

There is [Digitizing Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DigitizingTools/), which **Fill ring with a new feature** tool is useful for this case.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to GIS SE. You can create a polygon layer and draw square-shaped polygons on top of West Bank. Make sure to cover the empty areas well. Then use `Difference` tool in your toolbox to subtract the two and it will return the exact shape of the city which is empty in your image.